# Robolectric with AppCompat Library Incompatible Issue of AlertDialog

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

My application having Android Alertdialog which was tested by Robolectric framework.

```
ShadowAlertDialog.getLatestAlertDialog()
```

However, now that AlertDialog changed to android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog and because of that Robolectric giving me an incompatible types error.

```
Error:(81, 50) error: incompatible types
required: android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog 
found:    android.app.AlertDialog
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: [There's](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2232) an issue opened.

Answer (score 2):

My previous post was deleted due to providing a link. I'll re-post my answer with a clearer explanation:

I ported the existing shadows and the stuff I needed to use worked for me

```
@Suppress("unused")
@Implements(AlertDialog::class)
open class ShadowAlertDialog : ShadowDialog() {

    @RealObject
    private lateinit var realAlertDialog: AlertDialog

    private val items: Array<CharSequence>? = null
    private val clickListener: DialogInterface.OnClickListener? = null
    private val isMultiItem: Boolean = false
    private val isSingleItem: Boolean = false
    private val multiChoiceClickListener: DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener? = null

    private var custom: FrameLayout? = null

    val customView: FrameLayout
        get() = custom ?: FrameLayout(realAlertDialog.context).apply { custom = this }

    val adapter: Adapter?
        get() = shadowAlertController.adapter

    /**
     * @return the message displayed in the dialog
     */
    open val message: CharSequence
        get() = shadowAlertController.getMessage()

    /**
     * @return the view set with [AlertDialog.Builder.setView]
     */
    val view: View?
        get() = shadowAlertController.view

    /**
     * @return the icon set with [AlertDialog.Builder.setIcon]
     */
    val iconId: Int
        get() = shadowAlertController.iconId

    /**
     * @return return the view set with [AlertDialog.Builder.setCustomTitle]
     */
    val customTitleView: View?
        get() = shadowAlertController.customTitleView

    private val shadowAlertController: ShadowAlertController
        get() {
            val alertController = ReflectionHelpers.getField<Any>(realAlertDialog, "mAlert")
            return Shadow.extract<ShadowAlertController>(alertController)
        }

    /**
     * Simulates a click on the `Dialog` item indicated by `index`. Handles both multi- and single-choice dialogs, tracks which items are currently
     * checked and calls listeners appropriately.
     *
     * @param index the index of the item to click on
     */
    fun clickOnItem(index: Int) {
        val shadowListView = Shadow.extract<ShadowListView>(realAlertDialog.listView)
        shadowListView.performItemClick(index)
    }

    override fun getTitle(): CharSequence {
        return shadowAlertController.getTitle()
    }

    /**
     * @return the items that are available to be clicked on
     */
    fun getItems(): Array<CharSequence>? {
        val adapter = shadowAlertController.adapter ?: return null
        return Array(adapter.count) { adapter.getItem(it) as CharSequence }
    }

    public override fun show() {
        super.show()
        latestShadowAlertDialog = this
    }

    @Implements(AlertDialog.Builder::class)
    class ShadowBuilder

    companion object {

        private var latestShadowAlertDialog: ShadowAlertDialog? = null

        /**
         * @return the most recently created `AlertDialog`, or null if none has been created during this test run
         */
        val latestAlertDialog: AlertDialog?
            get() = latestShadowAlertDialog?.realAlertDialog

        /**
         * Resets the tracking of the most recently created `AlertDialog`
         */
        fun reset() {
            latestShadowAlertDialog = null
        }
    }
}

@Suppress("unused")
@Implements(className = ShadowAlertController.clazzName, isInAndroidSdk = false)
class ShadowAlertController {

    companion object {

        const val clazzName = "androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController"
    }

    @RealObject
    private lateinit var realAlertController: Any

    private var title: CharSequence? = null
    private var message: CharSequence? = null

    var view: View? = null
        @Implementation
        set(view) {
            field = view
            directlyOn<Any>(realAlertController, clazzName, "setView", ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(View::class.java, view))
        }

    var customTitleView: View? = null
        private set

    var iconId: Int = 0
        private set

    val adapter: Adapter?
        get() = ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod<ListView>(realAlertController, "getListView").adapter

    @Implementation
    @Throws(InvocationTargetException::class, IllegalAccessException::class)
    fun setTitle(title: CharSequence) {
        this.title = title
        directlyOn<Any>(realAlertController, clazzName, "setTitle", ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(CharSequence::class.java, title))
    }

    fun getTitle(): CharSequence = title ?: ""

    @Implementation
    fun setCustomTitle(customTitleView: View) {
        this.customTitleView = customTitleView
        directlyOn<Any>(realAlertController, clazzName, "setCustomTitle", ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(View::class.java, customTitleView))
    }

    @Implementation
    fun setMessage(message: CharSequence) {
        this.message = message
        directlyOn<Any>(realAlertController, clazzName, "setMessage", ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(CharSequence::class.java, message))
    }

    fun getMessage(): CharSequence = message ?: ""

    @Implementation(minSdk = LOLLIPOP)
    fun setView(resourceId: Int) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()).inflate(resourceId, null)
    }

    @Implementation
    fun setIcon(iconId: Int) {
        this.iconId = iconId
        directlyOn<Any>(realAlertController, clazzName, "setIcon", ReflectionHelpers.ClassParameter(Int::class.java, iconId))
    }
}
```

Register the shadows for your tests like this

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(
    shadows = [ShadowAlertDialog::class, ShadowAlertController::class, ...],
)
```

And use these in your tests like follows

```
val dialog = ShadowAlertDialog.latestAlertDialog!!
val shadowDialog = Shadow.extract<ShadowAlertDialog(dialog)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is our workaround (in Kotlin):

```
val alertDialog = ShadowDialog.getLatestDialog() as AlertDialog
alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE).performClick()
```